# IOWebSocketChannel Flutter & GraphQL Apollo

Tags: flutter, websocket, graphql

I'm having an issue connecting to a GraphQL endpoint using Web-sockets.

The issues are noted in the comments. I cannot get this working. It works on the browser (separate test application) so the server is fine.

```
IOWebSocketChannel? _channel;
StreamSubscription? _getSubscription;

connectToWebsocket(BuildContext context) {
  // Nothing to listen to. Auth users only.
  final auth = authProviderRead(context);
  if (auth.modelUser == null) {
    return;
  }

  _channel?.sink.close();
  _getSubscription?.cancel();

  final headers = {
    "Authorization": auth.jwt ?? "",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  };

  _channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(
    Uri.parse(getWebStockUrl()),
    headers: headers,
    protocols: ["graphql-ws"],
  );

  // Fails: Just fires "onDone"
  // _channel?.sink.add(jsonEncode({"data": subscriptionQuery}));

  // Fails with {"type":"connection_error","payload":{"message":"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Authorization')"}}
  // _channel?.sink.add(json.encode({"type": "connection_init"}));

  // Fails with {"type":"error","payload":{"message":"Invalid message type!"}}
  // _channel?.sink.add(jsonEncode(
  //   {
  //     "type": "data",
  //     "query": subscriptionQuery,
  //   },
  // ));

  _getSubscription = _channel!.stream.listen((message) {
    // Is never fired?
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print("Got live message");
      print(message);
    }
    // channel!.sink.add('received!');
    // channel!.sink.close();
  })
    ..onData((data) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("onData - WebSocket");
        print(data);
      }
    })
    ..onDone(() {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("onDone - WebSocket");
      }
    })
    ..onError((e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("onError - WebSocket");
        print(e);
      }
    });
}

const subscriptionQuery = r'''
  subscription Subscription { 
  gotChatMessage {
    messageResults {
      message {
        markdown
      }
    }
  }
}
''';
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out, there are some additional things that it requires.

From https://github.com/apollographql/subscriptions-transport-ws/blob/master/src/message-types.ts

```
  _channel?.sink.add(jsonEncode({
    "type": "connection_init",
    "payload": {"Authorization": auth.jwt}
  }));
  _channel?.sink.add(jsonEncode({
    "type": "start",
    "payload": {"query": subscriptionQuery}
  }));
```